# One JavaScript/jQuery Function Not Working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

So, I'm trying to use Wordpress for the "News" page on my website, but one of my js functions is just not working in Wordpress (works fine without wp).

Here is the HTML I've put in the Wordpress posts template:

```
<div class="posts">
    <h2>POST SUMMARY</h2>
    <a class="readmore" href="javascript:;">Read More</a>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <p>POST CONTENT</p> 
    <center><iframe>iFRAME CONTENT</iframe></center>
    <a class="readless" href="javascript:;">Read Less</a>
</div>
```

These functions are working fine:

```
// Showing only post preview on page load
$('.posts').not(':first').css({
    'height': '110px',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
});

// Hiding a.readmore when post is expanded
$('.readmore:first').addClass('full');

// Expanding post
$('.readmore').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('full');
    $(this).closest('.posts').css({
        'height': '',
        'overflow': ''
    });
});
```

This is the problem function (`.readless` collapses the post as it should, but `.readmore` remains hidden):

```
// Minimizing post
$('.readless').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    clicked.closest('.posts').css({'height': '110px','overflow': 'hidden'});
    clicked.closest('.posts').children('.readmore').removeClass('full');
});
```

Oh, and the CSS, in case it's not obvious:

```
a.readmore.full {
    display: none;
}
```

My only thought was that `.posts` already exists in wp's HTML, so I tried giving it a name attribute and targeting it (and its children) that way, but to no avail.

Any help and/or suggestion is, as always, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can troubleshoot Javascript by using the console in your browser. For example, you can try typing these commands to the console:

```
console.log( jQuery('.readless') );
console.log( jQuery('.readless').closest('.posts') );
console.log( jQuery('.readless').closest('.posts').children('.readmore') );
```

The output will tell you if jQuery is matching your elements correctly.

**Edit**: Turns out the OP was posting the code through the Rich Editor, and the `A` elements got wrapped with `P` elements. In this case, the `a.readmore` element was no longer a *child* of `div.posts`, but a *descendant* (a grandchild). Therefore, the jQuery selector is:

```
jQuery('.readless').closest('.posts').find('.readmore');
```

If you have difficulty matching the correct elements, always check your DOM using the browser's developer tools such as "inspect element".

Comment: Yeah, the log tells me what I already suspected: jQuery is matching `.posts` but not its children. I still don't know why, or how to get the proper child element. As I said, this functions works fine outside of WordPress.

Comment: What do you get if you put in `console.log( jQuery('.readless').closest('.posts').children() );`?

Comment: On closer examination, it looks like WP is putting `a.readmore` inside `<P></p>` tags. Any idea how I can target that with jQuery?

Comment: You said you put your code in "posts template", which file is that precisely?

Comment: I mean the "Add New Post" page of the WordPress Admin Dashboard.

Comment: Ok, well that explains it. You shouldn't really use the admin backend to input raw html, in fact, that capability is normally turned off for  security reasons. The correct way is described here: [Stepping into templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates). Anyway, you can use `jQuery('.readless').closest('posts').find('.readmore')`.

Comment: Thanks for that, and for the link. Today is literally my first time using WordPress, and I've got a ways to go :) Especially considering I know very little PHP and SQL.

Comment: Not that it's still remotely of interest, but it didn't work properly even after putting the raw HTML where it belongs. I ended up targeting the `.readmore` anchor like this: `clicked.closest('.posts').children('article').children('.entry-header').find('.readmore.full').removeClass('full');`.

Comment: Wouldn't `clicked.closest('.posts').find('.readmore.full')` suffice?

Comment: Close. Except it finds ALL the `.readmore`s in the document, not just the one in the closest `.posts`. There are several `.posts` on the page, each of which has the more and less links.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48213/discussion-between-p-enrique-and-mycompassspins)